# My language, gecho

Tags: c

I wrote a language in C, dubbed `gecho`. The code can be found [here](http://github.com/tekknolagi/gecho/tree/testing).

I'm writing this for a purely educational reason (not for school at all) and I just hope to make it Turing complete, and to improve the structure. The basic syntax is in the README. Let me know if you happen to do anything super cool with a gecho program.

Just some criticism (harsh, please) would be lovely!

> **functions.h:** functions to operate on the stack ->
>               i have all the commands here, really
>
> **gecho.c:** main REPL for interpreter ->
>           has main() and an eval() function that interprets each 'word'
>
> **gechoc.c:** main eval loop for compiler ->
>           has main() and an eval() function that interprets each 'word' and fprintfs >equivalent
>           C code
>
> **header.h:** template for compilation ->
>            includes necessary headers and is itself included while writing to a .c file
>
> **stack.h:** stack implementation ->
>           operations with the stack: push, pop, show, that kind of thing
>
> **structdef:** definitions for structs (like modes and constants) ->
>             has the mode struct defined, the constant struct defined
>
> **structs.h:** structs ->
>             holds the mode, constant, variable struct defined
>
> **usefunc.h:** gets all necessary headers and #defines some stuff ->
>             a catch-all for includes and preprocessor directives

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay, here are some things I noticed after a quick scan through the code:

The first thing that jumped at me that you put your function definitions in your header files. I'm not sure why you chose to do this, but it is almost definitely a bad idea. Please only put the prototypes in the header and put the definitions in c-files (and then adjust the build process accordingly).

Your header files also don't have any [#include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard). You should fix that as well.

---

You should also always compile your code with warnings enabled. Doing so will warn you about the following bugs:

- In functions.h there are two functions which call `printf` with an empty string as its parameter. Since that does nothing at all, this is either a bug (if you meant it to do something other than nothing) or just plain unnecessary code.
- In gecho.c you have a variable `tmp` that you never use. In gechoc.c you have a variable `msg` that you also never use.
- In both `eval` functions you never return a value even though the functions are declared to return an `int`. Since you never use their return value either, I suppose they should just be `void`.

You should also be aware that your code does not compile if you enable strict ansi compliance (no matter whether C90 or C99) on account of using several non-standard extensions like for example the `bool` datatype (I'm not going to list all of them here - you can just try to compile with `-ansi` and you can see the errors for yourself).

---

Both your `eval` functions are way too long. They also seem to be quite similar to each other in parts. I'd say this is definitely in need of some refactoring. You should split the functions into multiples shorter functions and move the common stuff out into functions that are shared between both components.

Also the `eval` function of the compiler should not actually be called `eval`. It does not actually evaluate anything, it just generates code. Consequently it should be called something along the lines of `codegen` or `generate_code`.

---

On a language design note I think the `..` command is rather badly named as it does not do what one would expect (or what I would expect at least): Given the fact that in most cases `opop` seems to do the same thing as `op`, but for the entire stack (e.g. `+` adds two numbers and `++` adds the entire stack) and the fact that `.` (pops and) prints one element, I'd expect `..` to (pop and) print the entire stack, instead of just popping it.

Comment: Thank you for your long feedback. Why is it bad to put functions in headers? Are single-line comments not allowed with `-ansi`? How do you suggest I refactor the eval/codegen functions? Also thank you for the tip - i'll rename `..` to `dels`.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Putting definitions into headers is bad because: 1. It will lead to linker errors if you try to link multiple objects that included the same header. 2. It makes modular compilation impossible (if multiple c files include the same header, the code in the header will be compiled each time, whereas if it was in its own .c file, it would be compiled only once). 3. You won't get forward-declarations for your functions for free (which you would if you had the prototypes in a header and included that in the .c file which contains the definitions).

Comment: @tekknolagi: On a related note I've just noticed that you also don't have any `#include` guards in your headers. You should fix that as well.

Comment: @tekknolagi: Single line comments are allowed by C99, but not by C90. `-ansi` uses C90 by default. If you use `-std=c99`, you won't get complaints about the single line comments anymore (but still about stuff like `bool`, `true` and `false` being undefined).

Comment: sepp2k: i thank you for the word on headers. also, what are #include guards? and i defined true and false as an enum named bool.

Comment: @tekknolagi: [#include guards](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) are what people do to prevent a header from accidentally being included more than once. It's common practice in C, as it quickly becomes very cumbersome to make sure each header is only included once otherwise.

Comment: added them and pushed

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you have some of basics of language development, so well done for a first start.

I'd say that you want to avoid things like your RES_SIZE and VAR_SIZE constants. Where do these numbers come from? Are they designed to be suitable for the system that you're running on? What about someone else's system? What about in five years? What about the system running on someone's phone? It's generally best to allocate resources as you need them, and to not place any arbitrary restrictions of how many of anything you can have. When system resources run out, you will get back error messages from functions like fork or malloc, and then you know you're out of resources.

You may think they're only there until you put a proper allocation system in place, but will you really remember to go back and fix them all? Best to do it right in the first place.

Have you read some books on language development. There are loads of them, and some of them are very good and very readable. If you take a week off programming, and instead read something like the dragon book (http://dragonbook.stanford.edu/), you will come back with a much clearer idea of what you're doing.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for the memory allocation tip and Dragon Book tip as well!